# .net mvc SendAsync - How to find error logs if a message can't be sent?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, smtp

I have the following class to send emails.

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)

        {

            if (message != null)

            {

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(message.Destination);
                mail.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com");
                mail.Subject = message.Subject;
                string Body = message.Body;
                mail.Body = Body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.test.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                //
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pass");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                return smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);

            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);

        }
    }
```

Our IT informed us that he open the port 587 on the firewall. However, the emails can't be sent.

In `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC2` logs I have the following messages without getting an error.

```
2021-02-08 12:02:13 192.168.1.2 GET /signalr/connect transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=1%2FM7LMZNVeWfN1mD1D9geTBdC7vVjo6nQRtD%2BrQv%2BVwUUdC6eE6jbKaIq2CUlrUsaylRVyJgz6fFqoQDsxJ9%2F77L8kizNCyZYkAs5nxK2T6Crz4xlKu9lAS1z9%2FHDen84sd7IVBASCnCm46jfQlrdg%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&tid=0 81 test@gmail.com 192.168.1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/88.0.4324.146+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.2:81/Account/ReSendEmailConfirmationTokenAsync?userID=51abfa03-6d09-40bb-8e4c-89117515ff&subject=Confirm%20your%20account 200 0 0 494899
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you debug your code? can the project work normally locally? does this problem only occur when published on iis? are there any related error messages in the Event Viewer?

Comment: @samwu You are right! I did not! And finally I found the issue. The email's password was expired! Thank you!